# pass object reference as function argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

Here I have a simple code to understand how `Object.create()` works. Here I have a common object to be used as prototype which is `prototypeObj`.`newObj` is an object which has its prototype set to `prototypeObj`. Here I have another object called `session` which has a property called `anotherObj`, and `anotherObj` has the same prototype as `newObj`. But adding new value to a property called foo which resides in the prototype of `anotherObj` , affect `newObj` too. Why am I experiencing this behaviour?

**Code:**

```js
var prototypeObj = {
  foo: [],
  addItemToFoo: function(add) {
    this.foo.push(add);
  }
}

function create(fooVal) {
  var myProto = Object.create(prototypeObj);
  myProto.foo = fooVal;
  return myProto;
}

var newObj = create([1, 2]); // initialized with [1,2]

session = {
  anotherObj: create(newObj.foo) // initialized with [1,2]
}

session.anotherObj.addItemToFoo(6); // pushed 6 to session.anotherObj.foo

console.log("newObj.foo is " + newObj.foo); // newObj also get 6 pushed to its foo property

console.log("anotherObj.foo is " + session.anotherObj.foo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo` is an array, it works by reference.

```
anotherObj: create(newObj.foo)
```

You are copying the reference here, so both your old and new object will have the same array reference to insert elements in. If you want to have to different array references, you should first copy it like this `create(newObj.foo.slice())`

https://jsfiddle.net/x8ftnh82/

Comment: @AL-zami what about now?

Comment: @AL-zami great :), notice that this wouldn't have happened with an `integer` or `string` for example. But it would also have happened with other objects like `{ something: 1 }`.

Comment: ya, objects are passed by reference... this makes sence now